# php regex replacing with number and character not null

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to escape everything from the uri except letters, numbers, -, and /, so I made the regex below and put it into a `preg_replace` function. But if I type something like `/dir/anotherDir<?<<<?>` it doesn't remove it to null it replaces the greater than and less than with `3C` and `3E` how can I fix this?

```
$uriPath = htmlentities($uriPath);

$patterns = array('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\/]/', '/\.+/', '/\.+\//', '/\.+\.+\//');

$uriPath = preg_replace($patterns, '', $uriPath);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @anubhava I am trying to clean a uri that is typed into the browser

Comment: Use `preg_quote` for escaping.

Comment: Move  $uriPath = htmlentities($uriPath); after $uriPath = preg_replace($patterns, '', $uriPath); line  .  Because htmlentites function escape chars your preg replace cant remove chars. If u move it after preg replace line. Its working

Comment: "typed into the browser" – just use javascript.

Comment: @PouyaDarabi unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: I test it . It work . Echo output after preg_replace and see output. Also u can remove htmlentites because html chars after preg_replace removing and u dont need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `rawurldecode()` on the path and that made everything work as expected. This is because it converts things like `%20` back to a space.